# How to debug PHP in MS Azure

Tags: php, azure, drupal, drupal-7

First things first: I was given the task to deploy a Drupal website on Azure.

Locally I use OS X running Apache and everything works ok. When I deploy the project to Azure, I get an error. After some debugging I isolated the error to this snippet of code:

```
private function getToken(){
    $ch = curl_init($this->host . $this->clientId . "&client_secret=" . $this->clientSecret);
    curl_setopt($ch,  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('accept: application/json',));
    $response = json_decode(curl_exec($ch));
    curl_close($ch);
    $token = $response->access_token;
    dvm($response, $name = NULL);
    return $token;
}
```

`dvm()` is a Drupal Devel function, but suffice to say that's sort of `print_r` for Drupal on steroids.

The problem I'm getting is that for whatever reason, `$result` is coming back `NULL`. When I run the same code on my local machine and on a Linux/Debian box, all worked as expected (I get an Object as a result of the `curl`).

This leads to the conclusion that Azure is not liking something in this piece code. The problem is finding out what. Any ideas?

Comment: please run phpinfo and check if curl is enabled, test the values of $this-> variables

Comment: Curl is enabled. What do you mean by `$this-> variables`? Pardon my ignorance but I'm not an expert in PHP.

Comment: @LuckyChingi means you can check whether the variables you set in `curl_init` are not null or right.

Comment: `$this->variables` are all set as expected. Is there a chance Azure is blocking the curl call to the external API?

Comment: Azure Web App will not block the curl call, we can test with the following code on Azure: `$ch = curl_init("www.bing.com"); 
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); 
        $output = curl_exec($ch); 
        print($output);
        curl_close($ch); `. By the way, you can check your Api server whether has a white list, which may block the HTTP request from Azure Web App.

Comment: @GaryLiu-MSFT Thanks for your reply. When you say "server whitelist" do you mean in my own code or within Azure configurable options (Unfortunately I don't have access to Azure control panel, which is managed by someone else within our business)?

Comment: Actually, I mean that your API server may have a white list which do not added your Azure endpoint in it, so the API server may block your request from Azure Web App. Here, the `$this->host` should be the url of you API server

Comment: That's not applicable in our case (its a public API behind https). Any other ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For a prod environment, `display_errors` is set `off` in PHP runtime on Azure Web Apps. We can open the setting for debugging via change the build-in PHP configurations.

Here are simple steps:

1, Add a `.user.ini` file to your root directory.

2, Add configuration settings to the .user.ini file using the same syntax you would use in a `php.ini` file. With your demand, your `.user.ini` file would contain this text:

`display_errors = On`

3, Deploy your web app.

4, Restart the web app.

You can read [official guide](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-php-configure/#how-to-change-the-built-in-php-configurations) for more information.

Furthermore, we can login in the Kudu console of our websites to manage our sites. The URL of Kudu console should be like: `https://{your_web_site_name}. scm.azurewebsites.net`, and click `Tools` => `Diagnostic dump` to download the diagnostic logs.

Additional, we can use [WebMatrix](http://www.microsoft.com/web/webmatrix/) to directly modify your code on Azure Web Apps.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Last issue I've got is to do with enabling email via php. Would you have any idea on how to get it to work? The error I'm getting would be resolved if I were to instal `sendmail` on Linux. How could I get it working on Azure?

Comment: As this problem is little relative with this thread, I suggest you to open a new thread, which will be benefit for other communities who have similar issue.

Comment: The question title was "how to debug PHP on Azure", this answers a different question of "how to turn on errors"

Comment: @pilavdzice, this is simple and general steps to change PHP configuration on Azure, including debug. turn on errors is a way for PHP debug. I don't know which way you'd like to debug PHP on Azure, and I found a post https://hajekj.net/2016/09/06/remotely-debugging-php-on-azure-web-apps-with-ngrok/ maybe can give you a different idea.

Comment: I meant to turn on debugging you need to add something like this to the .user.ini:  zend_extension = ".\bin\php_xdebug-2.2.1-5.3-vc9-nts.dll"
xdebug.remote_host="192.168.whatever.whatever"
xdebug.profiler_enable=1
xdebug.profiler_output_dir="D:\home\site\wwwroot\bin\xdebug_profiles"
xdebug.profiler_enable_trigger=1

Comment: @GaryLiu-MSFT Yes you posted great steps to change PHP config, but the question asked how to enable debugging. PHP has a debugger called XDebug (and others). Debuggers have features that let you follow along the code in real time execution, measure performance, and other things. Displaying errors is NOT debugging. Changing PHP config is not all that is needed to enable debugging either. Since this wrong answer is marked correct no one is posting the more complex correct answer.