# Azure Web App Http Error 500

Tags: wordpress, azure, azure-web-app-service, http-error, http-status-code-500

https://bucherid.azurewebsites.net/

the website can't be accessed normally and ended up with http error 500

But, when i logged in to
bucherid.azurewebsites.n*t/wp-login/
finally i can see the website content normally.

previously the site can be accessed normally and then from yesterday I don't know why but this http 500 happened.

are there solution for this?

from the failed requests traces, this is what appear
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TqL6F.png)

there's also error messages like this
"There is not enough space on the disk."

Comment: Firstly I suggest you could check your web app usage. You could follow this image shows to see the usage of your web app: http://imgur.com/a/TAJNy.   I suggest you could try to scale up your app service plan or delete the file in your web app.

Comment: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/GWE2H.png
  [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/TqL6F.png
These are the usage from the web app.

the website works just fine only when I have logged in wp-admin.
if I logged out from wp-admin or other people accessed the web will still show the http 500

Comment: Btw, this is what I got from the Failed Request Tracing Logs
https://ibb.co/mciYk5

Comment: are you using MVC? could this be a problem with your routes?

Comment: what's MVC? routes?
I don't understand much about the problem. The only thing that i know is previously it was working just fine but now for some reason, if I don't login to wp-admin, the website can't be accessed.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the information you have provided, it can not tell what has caused this issue yet. I suggest you enable the **Detailed error message** functionality through the Azure portal. the screenshot below is to show where to turn on that.

[image]

After that done, you should have log files under the directory `d:/home/LogFiles/DetailedErrors` in your Azure server. You can refer to the [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-web/web-sites-enable-diagnostic-log#a-namedownloada-how-to-download-logs) to know how to download them. These files will provide more specific details for the HTTP errors.

Additionally, you can also enable PHP run-time error log by changing the built-in PHP configurations. For more info, please refer to [How to debug PHP in MS Azure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33241711/how-to-debug-php-in-ms-azure/33276962#33276962).

Comment: Tried that and got some log files. here's the log file content
https://ibb.co/ip3UNv
https://ibb.co/hemupa
https://ibb.co/gu5LUa

#/  i have checked the ftp and there's no problem with the font file
https://ibb.co/nDxpNv

#/ even the index.php that was said to cause the error didn't have anything problematic in it.
https://ibb.co/eO2Ohv

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your SKU, there are limitations in how much disk space you get. See the [App Service Pricing](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/app-service/) page for details.