# How do i do a Contact form hosted in an Azure app using Mailgun?

Tags: azure-web-app-service, mailgun

I finally got my html website working [in an Azure App.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47877650/how-do-i-host-a-public-static-site-as-a-web-app)
Now I want to add a Contact Form.
I have done a simple HTML form that calls the MailGun API but nothing happens when I click submit.
There are no errors showing in the browser.

I followed the instructions [here to create the form.](http://blog.thepascalbecker.com/2015/02/17/why-i-ditched-phps-mail-for-mailgun-and-how-you-can-too/)

Comment: Those instructions reference submitting the form to send.php.   Is PHP enabled for your Azure setup?  Did you remember to change the api_key, api_domain, and send_to values?  If PHP is enabled did you check the Azure error log?  (I mention PHP twice since a "static" site implies no server-side scripting.)

Comment: @DaveS I have set the keys. Also if I go into Application Settings I can see that the PHP version is 5.6

Comment: I can see some trace files in Kudu Debug Console Is that where I look for logs?

Comment: I haven't used PHP with Azure yet, so you'll need to ask someone else or google that.  You might try adding error reporting to the top of send.php - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1053424/how-do-i-get-php-errors-to-display

Comment: Thanks. Just adding the index.php and php.ini did not seem to work., investigating https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/silverlining/2012/10/16/getting-error-info-for-php-sites-in-windows-azure-web-sites/

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3062324/what-is-curl-in-php

Comment: Is your issue resolved? If not, you can edit your question adding more details for further analysis. [How to debug PHP in MS Azure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33241711/how-to-debug-php-in-ms-azure/33276962#33276962)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out that I had incorrect settings in

```
  $api_key = 'INSERT_API_KEY_HERE';
  $api_domain = 'INSERT_DOMAIN_HERE'; 
  $send_to = 'YOUR_EMAIL';
```

This became apparent after displaying the error from the Ajax call.
[As explained here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47894790/how-do-i-display-messages-from-php-called-from-ajax-inside-an-azure-app)